# Spring native support for OIDC workflow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect, okta

I am trying to enable OIDC authN and authZ workflow for my spring-java-web application. Ideally I wanted to do it in a IDP agnostic way.i.e.This application could be integrated with only and any one of the Azure AD,OKTA,AWS SSO,Google-auth by deployment admin.And I want users to be redirected to whatever provider the application is integrated with.

With OIDC as a standard, my understanding is i should be able to write a OIDC auth processing filter that should work with any of the providers. The necessary config that varies per provider ( auth url,client id,secret,JWKS url to get the provider keys etc) will be passed to this filter/rest template as parameters.

- Q.1 Is it possible to implement provider agnostic OIDC filter? Can someone give any pointers?

I am aware that Spring natively provides Oauth2 libraries/apis like AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails, OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter . However I do not see any OIDC native processing filter in built. Is there any?

I tried and understood the workflow as given in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect .However when i try to tweak this code to make it work with Azure AD it fails. Thats because Azure AD requires

1. The response_type parameter must include id_token.
2. The request must include `nonce` parameter to be set in request.

AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails does not support such param. Given that OIDC is a common standard ,

- Q-2. I fail to understand why every provider still has different requirements? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of OIDC . Infact I read that google throws error if you pass `nonce`
- Q-3. Are there any spring native ways to configure these additional provider specific params like `nonce` , `promt`, additional `response-type` ,preferable with examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems with Spring Security OIDC are that you're using the legacy OAuth library (at least that's what the baeldung article is illustrating). OAuth2 and OIDC are part of Spring Security 5.x now and not a separate project. There's an OIDC client "login-client" in this example: https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2-protocol-patterns that might show different. Yes, OIDC should allow you to swap providers in and out although not all OIDC providers will implement everything (e.g. discovery, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @sdoxsee .OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter and OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter are working together to handler redirection based on registrationId.But this id is being passed explicitly when user clicks on a link. In my case. if the application is integrated with Google.i want users to implicitly get redirected to google for authN instead of asking them to click on link. In baeldung article this was achieved using same url as "LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint", Filter processing url and redirect url and OAuth2ClientContextFilter. How can i do this in Spring 5?

Answer (score 0):

I had missed this question, so sorry for the (very) late answer.

I wrote a [Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) with exactly that purpose: propose an OpenID Provider agnostic starter with which OAuth2 clients and resource servers could, in most cases, be configured with just application properties. This includes things like:

- the claim to use as username
- claims to use a source for Spring authorities
- extra query param to include in authorization request like the `audience` required by Auth0
- small variations around the standard when it comes to logout like have Cognito and Auth0

Of course, what this starter does is just proposing defaults and you can override anything (but this requires some Java code).

For Q2, there are 3 categories of features in OpenID standard:

- required by the standard (when "must" is used in the RFC). There are very few violations of the standard by OpenID Providers (I only noticed minor ones regarding logout from 2 of the ones I tried).
- suggested by the standard (when "may" is used in the RFC). Unfortunately some OPs are more touchy than others and this even depends on the version you use (like the required `audience` in the request to Auth0 authorization endpoint). So you have no choice than referring to the doc of each provider :/
- intentionally excluded from it (roles, groups and anything related to permissions is a noticeable sample). Each vendor implements such features his own way with private claims. Again, no other choice than checking in their docs what they propose.

For Q3 yes, but it is not as simple as using "my" starter: provide with an authorization request resolver. You can have a look at how I implemented mine [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/synchronised/client/SpringAddonsOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java) (or [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/reactive/client/SpringAddonsServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java) if you're on the reactive side of the force).